# How can I create a camera fly-through effect in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, animation, camera, matlab-figure

[image]I would like to implement the fly-through effect as shown in [this nice example](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/example-moving-the-camera-through-a-scene.html). First I created a figure from matrix `hm`, a 300X300 matrix by using the `surf` function:

```
surf(hm);
```

Then, I defined an animated line from variables `x`, `y`, and `z` and displayed on the figure as follows:

```
curve = animatedline;
curve.LineWidth = 6;
curve.Color = [ 1 0 1];
for i = 1:length(x)
  addpoints(curve, x(i), y(i), z(i));
  drawnow;
end
```

Then, I wanted to implement the fly-through effect so that the camera will move along the line. I tried this code piece I took from the example above and I slightly modified it:

```
for i = 1:length(x)
  campos([(x(i) -5), (y(i)-5), 0]);
  camtarget([x(i), y(i), z(i)]);
  drawnow;
end
```

But the camera doesn't move as I intended. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mimic the behavior of the linked example, you need to have both the camera target *and* camera position moving along your curve defined by `(x, y, z)`. The way you've written it above, the camera target moves along the curve, but the camera position is always offset from the target by `(-5, -5)` in the `xy` plane and sitting at `z = 0`. If you want the camera to follow the curve behind the target, you should try something like this:

```
for iPoint = 6:numel(x)
  campos([x(iPoint-5) y(iPoint-5) z(iPoint-5)]);  % Note the index is shifted, not the value
  camtarget([x(iPoint) y(iPoint) z(iPoint)]);
  drawnow;
end
```

If you don't want the camera moving along the same curve, and instead want it to always be at a fixed offset from your moving camera target, you could try this:

```
offset = [-5 -5 0];  % X, Y, and Z offset from target
for iPoint = 1:numel(x)
  campos([x(iPoint)+offset(1) y(iPoint)+offset(2) z(iPoint)+offset(3)]);
  camtarget([x(iPoint) y(iPoint) z(iPoint)]);
  drawnow;
end
```

Finally, if you'd like to control the speed of the animation, you can replace the [`drawnow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) command with a call to [`pause`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html). Note that [a call to `pause` is equivalent to a call to `drawnow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html#burd3gs-3) in that it will force an update of graphics objects. You can also animate graphics using a [timer object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html), as I illustrate [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716877/52738).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the camera still moves different from what I intended.

Comment: I edited my question and added the figure with the animated line to further explain my intention. I  am trying to make the camera follow the line but a little bit behind it. It would be great if I be able to change the speed so it can move slowly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Newprogrammer: It's still a little unclear exactly the sort of camera movement you want, but I added another option to my answer, along with how you can control the speed.